# Thread level information about a process in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I need to get the resources utilized by different threads that runs in a specific process. Suppose I give a particular pid as the input, I must get the information(Time spent in User,Kernel mode) about the threads for that pid. Is there a Proc file which takes care of all the details about the threads?

Answer (score 2):

The information for the threads of a process can be found in the `task` subdirectory of the proc dir:

```
/proc/[pid]/task/[tid]/stat
```

Additionally, `top` can display thread information:

```
top -H -p [pid]
```